# Change what the "default" landing page is

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, user-accounts

I prefer to go to the Question -> Newest section of all Stack Overflow family websites. However, when clicking on the logo for the given website, it sends me to the "Active" tab. I would like if there was a setting inside the user account to control the default action.

...and no please no tips on "Updating my bookmark" or of the such. It would be great if I could just click the logo, and be taken there.

Comment: Update your bookmark.

Comment: Don't Update your bookmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look to the right of the logo.  See that big box that says `Questions` ?  Click it.

If it doesn't go to the newest tab, click the newest tab and SO will remember that you want to go to the newest tab next time you click `Questions`.

I haven't done significant testing to see if it'll remember your tab across browser sessions, etc, but you only have to do two clicks to set it up, and then the `Questions` button takes you there for at least the remainder of your browsing session.

Comment: Hmm, ok. At least it seems to work some of time time... 

Regardless I thought it would be a pretty simple feature-request to be at least looked at by staffers and members alike.

Comment: yes, tabs and sort orders are generally "sticky" throughout SO -- we remember your last setting as long as you are a logged in user

Comment: Meh, works for now. Thought I would at least stick it out as a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

They probably won't add a preference setting to set your default homepage, but...

You can modify [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39622) (excellent) GreaseMonkey script to do that for you.

<sub>or update your bookmarks</sub>

Comment: lol. I understand this wouldn't be a change "just for me". It would be an addition to all users of course. Perhaps some users prefer to be taken to the Bounty section, or a specific time tab (week, month...)

This is a general request, trust me I *know* I'm not that special!

Comment: @urda, so you are asking for a preference setting at the user level? (just to be clear)

Comment: yes. It would be an option in your profile, with various dropdown or check boxes to select your "landing page" when you go to the root of the site (logged in of course) or click on the logo for the site.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the design decision to have default links go to the Active list is by design.  the desired user behavior is to look at new answers as well as new questions so the answers will be checked and voted on as frequently as the questions.

It also places focus on the real-time nature of the site, encouraging programmers to 'best' each other in active questions.

While your request might be nice for a small fraction of users, I suspect that since it can be 'fixed' on the user's end, it's not liable to attract enough attention to make them re-think their original decision.

Answer (score 0):

I use Newest as my default for the Questions tab on all Stack Exchange sites, and that works well for me on Internet Explorer.  However, on the iOS Mobile App it does not work and I have to constantly change from Active to Newest - but that's another story.

On **Meta GIS Stack Exchange** we have a **[Q&A](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3637/at-what-point-if-ever-is-an-edit-trivial-enough-to-warrant-rejection)** at the moment which has re-raised an ongoing perception that many edits of old Questions prevent new Questions getting due attention.  I have never seen this as a problem, because I know that choosing **Newest** on the browser makes that stick to the Questions tab, and as a backup I simply use **https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest** to always access the Newest queue.

However as soon as I hit the main icon on the site (at top left, like I suspect most must) it takes me to https://gis.stackexchange.com/ and the **Active** queue, ignoring that I have chosen Newest everywhere else.

I think your request to have the default landing page be to the Newest queue is an important one because I think it would  reduce tension in some Stack communities.

If this default is already a site specific setting I would be keen to be made aware of that.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the the official word will be no.

Why?

Because there are several features in place to bump content back to the top of the "Active" listing that don't affect the "Newest" page, and those features are integral to the way the site works.

If you want to fix it for yourself, you browser has a bookma...ah heck!